# How to select option from a dropdown when there is optgroup in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to select an option using Selenium in python.

Below is my code:from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests as r

import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url1="https://cannacabana.com/collections/all?page=1"

driver.get(url1)

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#store-select")))).select_by_visible_text('bayview')

---

I am getting timeout error, could it be because the website has Optgroup? I am not able to find a way through it. [image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it uses ".//" so Optgroup doesn't matter. You can see the implementation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/select.html#Select.select_by_visible_text).

I believe value="bayview" is not visible_text so you should use select_by_value() instead.

Comment: It gives me TimeoutException    error when I use select_by_value() instead